# How to locate google map with current location in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app,In this i am using google map to show user current location.The problem is when i open the app first time it shows blue map screen, and now i open the map again 2nd time then at this time map shows correct result with current location.This happen in targetsdkversion>23 and targetsdkversion<23 both the versions.Only the first time dosenot shows the correct map.Following is the code i am using.And how i validate the map whether map shows correct location or not ?

```
//java

public class Start_Activity1 extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    //Our Map
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public static final int REQUEST_ID_ACCESS_COURSE_FINE_LOCATION = 100;

    //To store longitude and latitude from map
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;
    String caddress;
    EditText eddate;
    EditText edtime;
    EditText seats1 ;
    public static TextView tvtime,tvdate;
    Button btime,bdate;

    //Buttons
    private ImageButton buttonSave;
    private ImageButton buttonCurrent;
    private ImageButton buttonView;

    private Button btnProceed, btnskip, btnClocation;

    String strAdd, start_point, start_time, no_seats, mob_no, stime, seats;
    TextView tvmap,textview;
    int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;

    private boolean loggedIn = false;
    public static String email;

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 100;

    private ProgressDialog myProgress;

    //Google ApiClient
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        tvmap=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_map);
        textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_euser);

        tvdate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_sdate);
        //    tvtime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_stime);
        seats1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_nseats);

        //date and time
        // datetime();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault());
        tvdate.setText(cal.getTime().toLocaleString());
        //   tvtime.setText(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));


        //progress bar
        myProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        myProgress.setTitle("Map Loading ...");
        myProgress.setMessage("Please wait...");
        myProgress.setCancelable(true);
        // Display Progress Bar.
        myProgress.show();

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //Initializing googleapi client
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        //Initializing views and adding onclick listeners
        btnProceed=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sproceed);
        //    btnskip=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_skip);
        //    btnClocation=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_clocation);

        btnProceed.setOnClickListener(this);
        //    btnClocation.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if(!enabled) {
            showDialogGPS();
        }

        super.onResume();
    }

    private void showDialogGPS() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle("Enable GPS");
        builder.setMessage("Please enable GPS");
        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                startActivity(
                        new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                getCurrentLocation();
                moveMap();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Ignore", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == btnProceed){

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);
            mob_no = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.PHONE_SHARED_PREF, "Not Available");
            textview.setText(String.valueOf(mob_no));

            //    getCurrentLocation();
            //    moveMap();
            if (loggedIn) {
                //We will start the Profile Activity
                submitForm();
                hsubmitForm();
                Intent i=new Intent(Start_Activity1.this,Index_Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
               // smsForm();
                //    Toast.makeText(Start_Activity.this, "You Submitted Details Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }

    //saving to database
    private void submitForm() {

        start_point = tvmap.getText().toString();
        start_time = tvdate.getText().toString();
        no_seats = seats1.getText().toString();
        mob_no = textview.getText().toString();
        //  Toast.makeText(this, "Signing up...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new StartAsync(this).execute(start_point, start_time, no_seats, mob_no);
    }

    //saving to database
    private void hsubmitForm() {

        start_point = tvmap.getText().toString();
        stime = tvdate.getText().toString();
        seats = seats1.getText().toString();
        mob_no = textview.getText().toString();
        //  Toast.makeText(this, "Signing up...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new SHistoryAsync(this).execute(mob_no, start_point, seats, stime);
    }

    private void smsForm() {

        mob_no = textview.getText().toString();
        //  Toast.makeText(this, "Signing up...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new SmsAsync(this).execute(mob_no);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    //Getting current location
    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        mMap.clear();
        //Creating a location object

        if(getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion>=23) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //     if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.//

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling

            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

        if (location != null) {
            //Getting longitude and latitude
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();

            //    tvmap.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

            //    strAdd = getCompleteAddressString(latitude, longitude);
            //    tvmap.setText("Current Address : " + strAdd);
            getCompleteAddressString(latitude, longitude);
            //moving the map to location
            moveMap();
        }

    }

    //Function to move the map
    private void moveMap() {
        //String to display current latitude and longitude
        String msg = latitude + ", "+longitude;

        //Creating a LatLng Object to store Coordinates
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        //Adding marker to map
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng) //setting position
                .draggable(true) //Making the marker draggable
                .title("Current Location")); //Adding a title

        //Moving the camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        //Animating the camera
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        getCurrentLocation();
        myProgress.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        //Clearing all the markers
        mMap.clear();

        //Adding a new marker to the current pressed position
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        //Getting the coordinates
        latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

        //Moving the map
        moveMap();
    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    private String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {
        String strAdd = "";
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
            if (addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:");

                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }
                strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                tvmap.setText(strAdd);
                Log.w("My Current loction address", "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
            } else {
                Log.w("My Current loction address", "No Address returned!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.w("My Current loction address", "Canont get Address!");
        }
        return strAdd;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the

                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    //    getCurrentLocation();
                    //    moveMap();
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(Start_Activity1.this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: mmm... I think that "the blue map" it's water in map, maybe it's reports a bad location or maybe it takes up a lot of time to show the location, try to change the method which you get current location, or try "hardcoding" latitude/longitude and open the first time to prove if it's the method which you get your location or another issue

Answer (score 2):

the 'blue screen' is the atlantic ocean. it's because the first time the current location is 0,0. Out of this reason you should get the current location before starting the map.

Comment: what i do this?

Comment: you can use a locationAcitivity and start the mapActivity from the locationActivity

Comment: https://github.com/treehouse/android-location-example-refactored/tree/master/app/src/main/java/teamtreehouse/com/iamhere